# Bug in Django querySet?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to develop a friends module to get more aquainted with django. Now there appeared some very strange behavior i can't follow. It's a bit hard to follow i guess, but I would really appreciate some help.

When i instantiate a queryset to update some values django produces the right sqlquery but no data is being updated in my mysql db.

Even if i print the result django tells me the right values which "should" come from the db...but in fact it's not?

My queries look like the following:

```
friend_update=Friends.objects.filter(user_me=self.user_id, user_he = friend_id, 
                          permission_he = True, 
                          permission_me = True).update(permission_me=False)
see_friend_update=Friends.objects.filter(user_me=self.user_id, user_he = friend_id, 
                          permission_he = True, permission_me = False)
#Save to DB#
for item in see_friend_update:
    item.save()

for i in see_friend_update:
    print "user me is %s with id %d permission_me set to %s, user_he is %s with id %d " %\
            (i.user_me,i.user_me.id,i.permission_me, i.user_he, i.user_he.id)

### After updating friends permissions, this sets the permission of the counterpart        

friend_update_vice_versa = Friend.objects.filter(user_me=friend_id, user_he = self.user_id, 
                            permission_he = True,
                            permission_me = True).update(permission_he=False)
 see_friend_update_vice = Friend.objects.filter(user_me=friend_id, user_he = self.user_id,
                            permission_he = False, permission_me = True)
for e in see_friend_update_vice:
    print "user me is %s with id %d permission_he set to%s, user_he is %s with id %d " % \
        (e.user_me,e.user_me.id,e.permission_he, e.user_he, e.user_he.id)
```

Django gives out the following values:

user me is tester with id 2 permission_me set toFalse (in DB it's still "True"!), user_he is tester232 with id 1

user me is tester232 with id 1 permission_he set toFalse (in DB it's still "True"!), user_he is tester with id 2

user me is tester with id 2 permission_me set toFalse(This works really!), user_he is tester232 with id 1

I hope i explained the problem well enough so that following is not too hard...

Comment: Could this be due to the DB transaction level being repeatable read?

Comment: Why aren't you doing a `save()` on each updated object?

Comment: @S.Lott: ---edited--do i have to make a save()? I tried to: for item in c:
   item.save()...no change...

Comment: @StephenPaulger do i circumvent the problem by doing a commit like: for item in c:
   item.save() ? If so...this doesn't change the result...

Comment: @Jurudocs: Please **update** the question to show the code you ran and the results you expected.

Comment: @Jurudocs: Since your indentation is a complete mess, you didn't really clarify anything.  Please **update** the question to be readable, with proper indentation.

Comment: Why is the first assumption that there's some bug in Django. Django is community-developed and thoroughly tested. Your code is not. I'd say the odds are on you doing something silly, not Django being broken.

Comment: okay...sorry well than maybe tell me about my sillyness. this was a question and not a statement

Comment: Your question is badly stated. Without proper indentation this code is impossible to follow, this is Python after all. I have made an edit suggestion, I hope it's correct. You could further improve the code by adding descriptive variable names.

Comment: thanks for editing...i will try my best!

Comment: @ChrisPratt maybe it is a bug...it is a caching problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured out what the problem is: it is the caching of the queryset. I still think it is a bug..but this solves the problem:

```
from django.db import transaction
a=Friends.objects.filter(user_me=self.user_id, user_he = friend_id, permission_he =True, permission_me = True).update(permission_me=False)
transaction.enter_transaction_management()
transaction.commit()
```

So it was NOT my silly code i guess....

Comment: Except... no one else has to do that, sooo... most likely you've already messed with the transaction management somewhere and didn't clean up after yourself.

Comment: @ChrisPratt maybe its because i'm switching the variables in the second queryset...i don't know! And i'm sorry to say... but i didn't mess with transaction management somewhere else. Thank you for your enlightening comments and help! And for your downvotes ;-P

Comment: I've never needed to do `from django.db import transaction`. This is not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing

```
for item in see_friend_update:
    item.save()
```

from your code? It doesn't seem to do anything useful.